# Codeigniter - Account is logging out after some time

Tags: php, codeigniter

After some time the account is logging out even if I've put sess_expiration = 0.
I tried to change in config files different values but still didn't work.
I would appreciate it if someone would help me with this one.

This is my config file:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'user_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: Are you by any chance testing the responsiveness of the website/app you're implementing (with DevTools)?

Comment: Also which version of CodeIgniter?

Comment: CodeIgniter 2 uses the user agent string to identify user sessions. Some browsers change the user agent string when switching between the "normal" desktop resolution and the simulated mobile/tablet resolutions. This breaks CI sessions. It is not necessarily the problem in your case, but it may be.

Comment: I understand but I'm not switching resolutions, it's not the problem in my case. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is tried to the `sess_time_to_update`,

however, this has been extensively tested. Try setting it to 30 seconds to confirm:

###### Code:

```
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 30;
```

If I use your config settings (or mine) I am not having any problems with getting logged out.

Comment: I've tried also to put $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 10; and it logged me out after some time. Thank you for the response anyway

Comment: You might also get better results by setting $config['sess_time_to_update'] to a value that is much closer to $config['sess_expiration'].

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
```